# mysql query to find records with same multiple fields

Tags: mysql

if I have a mysql table `person` and I want to find the person.id's of the people that have same name and from the same country, how would I do that?

something like:

```
select * 
from person p 
join person p2 
where p.country = p2.country and p.name = p2.name
```

but the example above if obviously not the way to go :\

Answer (score 0):

Your JOIN is incorrect, try

```
SELECT p.id as first, p2.id as duplicate 
FROM person p 
JOIN person p2 ON p.country = p2.country AND p.name = p2.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Where` keyword however in sql we always use `ON` with `joins` so

replace

```
where  p.country = p2.country and p.name = p2.name
```

to

```
ON  p.country = p2.country and p.name = p2.name
```

Comment: You have switched your code lines

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Oops! Thanks for letting me know +1